# Laravel MorphMany Relationship - What am I missing?

Tags: laravel

I have the defaults `users` table which I've altered to have `userable_type` and `userable_id`. I have various models, eg `BursaryAdministrator` and `BursaryProvider` and users can belong to either.

BA/BP Model:

```php
public function users() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Users', 'userable');
}
```

Users Model:

```php
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

During my migration, I've created a default `BursaryAdministrator` and `BursaryProvider` and a couple of users. I want to assign them to each:

```php
$bp = \App\BursaryProvider::first();
$user = User::find(2);
$bp->users()->associate($user);

$ba = \App\BursaryAdministrator::first();
$user = User::find(3);
$ba->users()->associate($user);
```

However, they're not linking as the `userable_type` / `userable_id` fields are null. I've tried both 'associate' and 'attach'.
Whats the correct what to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to `save()` the user after association, i.e.:

```
$bp = \App\BursaryProvider::first();
$user = User::find(2);
$bp->users()->associate($user);
$user->save()

$ba = \App\BursaryAdministrator::first();
$user = User::find(3);
$ba->users()->associate($user);
$user->save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but (userable_type / userable_id) still null in the database.

Comment: Ok I think there is a missing save on $user, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: i havent tried it - but that doesnt seem right at all. why would i have to save on a completely different variable ? Nothing has been done to it, its just a pointer / reference

Comment: You have to save the user because the user table holds `userable_type` and `userable_id` and because there is a clear example in the docs in which he does a save after an associate, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: Thanks, but referring to that example in the docs, then that would mean I would have to call $bp->save() and $ba->save() respectively, not $user->save
That makes more sense - I will give it a try and revert back...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this was the correct way at the end of the day:

```
    $bp = \App\BursaryProvider::first();
    $user = User::find(2);
    $user->userable()->associate($bp);
    $user->save();

    $ba = \App\BursaryAdministrator::first();
    $user = User::find(3);
    $user->userable()->associate($ba);
    $user->save();
```

Thanks to @dparoli for pointing me in the right direction.